# Whats wrong with this shell file its like the JVM is not working or something

Tags: java, shell, jvm, sh

Can someone please help me. I try using this to give it more memory to my JVM but i think somethings wrong with it. Thanks. Heres the code

```
#!/bin/sh 
export CLASSPATH=.:dist/MythStory.jar:dist/mina-core.jar:dist/slf4j-api.jar:dist/slf4j-jdk14.jar:dist/mysql-connector-java-bin.jar
java -Xmx700m  -Dwzpath=wz/ -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=filename.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=passwd -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=filename.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=passwd -Drecvops=recvops.properties -Dsendops=sendops.properties net.world.WorldServer
```

Comment: It launches the JVM but the ram given is the same as without it

Comment: How do you measure `ram given`? What does your program do? What do you do to eat up all the memory?

Comment: with this http://puu.sh/34wjr.png also I run a virtual server of a game thats why i need that much memory allocated

Comment: The memory will be allocated when it is needed, not before.

Comment: No problem. I added it as an answer, since it sounds like it was the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `-Xmx` flag doesn't cause the JVM to allocate all the memory immediately, but when it is needed.

You will have to stress your server or let it run for a while to see if the memory gets allocated correctly.